# Selecting data if condition is true

Tags: php, mysql, select, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm having problems explaining the problem even for myself, so I created an image since it's easier to understand.

Table structure: [image]

I want to select the data from the blue fields if the red field is empty and green field is true. How do I do this?
I've been wrestling with this for quite some time now.

Can't change the table structure since it's from the wordpress contactform7 to database plugin.

I'd be very grateful for any help :)

Just selecting an email works fine,

```
SELECT field_value FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits WHERE field_name = 'your-email'
```

Now I only want to select the email if the field_value = '' WHERE field_name = 'has-wp-user'..

So what I want is kinda like this;

```
SELECT field_value FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits WHERE field_name = 'your-email' IF has-wp-user = 'false'
```

Ish.

Is something along that way possible?

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` (
  `submit_time` decimal(16,4) NOT NULL,
  `form_name` varchar(127) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_name` varchar(127) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_value` longtext CHARACTER SET utf8,
  `field_order` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `file` longblob,
  KEY `submit_time_idx` (`submit_time`),
  KEY `form_name_idx` (`form_name`),
  KEY `field_name_idx` (`field_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumpning av Data i tabell `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits`
--

INSERT INTO `wp_cf7dbplugin_submits` (`submit_time`, `form_name`, `field_name`, `field_value`, `field_order`, `file`) VALUES
('1387497601.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'has-wp-user', '', 0, NULL),
('1387497601.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'paid-membership-fee', 'true', 1, NULL),
('1387497601.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-name', 'Firstname Lastname ', 2, NULL),
('1387497601.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-email', 'email@mail.se', 3, NULL),
('1387497601.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-adress', 'theroad 12', 4, NULL),
('1387497601.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-zip', '76045', 5, NULL),
('1387497601.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-postal-area', 'postalarea', 6, NULL),
('1387497601.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-phonenumber', '0123456789', 7, NULL),
('1387497602.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'has-wp-user', '', 0, NULL),
('1387497602.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'paid-membership-fee', 'true', 1, NULL),
('1387497602.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-name', 'Firstname lastname', 2, NULL),
('1387497602.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-email', 'email@mail.se', 3, NULL),
('1387497602.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-adress', 'singövägen 156', 4, NULL),
('1387497602.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-zip', '76045', 5, NULL),
('1387497602.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-postal-area', 'grisslehamn', 6, NULL),
('1387497602.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-phonenumber', '0123456789', 7, NULL),
('1387584003.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'has-wp-user', '', 0, NULL),
('1387584003.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'paid-membership-fee', 'true', 1, NULL),
('1387584003.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-name', 'Firstname Lastname', 2, NULL),
('1387584003.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-email', 'email@mail.se', 3, NULL),
('1387584003.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-adress', 'gryta hagväg 6', 4, NULL),
('1387584003.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-zip', '76175', 5, NULL),
('1387584003.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-postal-area', 'norrtälje', 6, NULL),
('1387584003.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-phonenumber', '0123456789', 7, NULL),
('1387584004.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'has-wp-user', 'true', 0, NULL),
('1387584004.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'paid-membership-fee', '', 1, NULL),
('1387584004.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-name', 'Firstname Lastname', 2, NULL),
('1387584004.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-email', 'email@mail.se', 3, NULL),
('1387584004.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-adress', 'bergstigen 7', 4, NULL),
('1387584004.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-zip', '76192', 5, NULL),
('1387584004.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-postal-area', 'norrtälje', 6, NULL),
('1387584004.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-phonenumber', '0123456789', 7, NULL),
('1387584005.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'has-wp-user', '', 0, NULL),
('1387584005.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'paid-membership-fee', 'true', 1, NULL),
('1387584005.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-name', 'Firstname Lastname', 2, NULL),
('1387584005.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-email', 'email@mail.se', 3, NULL),
('1387584005.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-adress', 'robertsväg10 ', 4, NULL),
('1387584005.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-zip', '76045', 5, NULL),
('1387584005.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-postal-area', 'grisslehamn', 6, NULL),
('1387584005.8300', 'Bli medlem', 'your-phonenumber', '0123456789', 7, NULL);
```

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs

Comment: Is there a column that groups those rows together, like a user_id or something? If yes, your problem is as good as solved.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/if-statement.html

Comment: So each unique user id defined simply by (submit_time, form_name)? This seems like a rather weak key - but we can works with it. See amended solution below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
*
from
my_table m inner join (
  select
  m.*
  from
  my_table m
  group by form_name, submit_time
  having sum(
    (field_name = 'has-wp-user' and field_value = '') 
    or 
    (field_name = 'paid-membership-fee' and field_value = 'true')
  ) = 2
) sq on m.form_name = sq.form_name and m.submit_time = sq.submit_time
where m.field_name in ('your-name', 'your-email');
```

- see it working live in an <kbd>[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d97837/2/0)</kbd> (updated with your new data)

The idea behind it is, that each field_name belongs to a group. I assumed here, that it's the combination of form_name and submit_time columns. With this subquery

```
  select
  m.*
  from
  my_table m
  group by form_name, submit_time
  having sum(
    (field_name = 'has-wp-user' and field_value is null) 
    or 
    (field_name = 'paid-membership-fee' and field_value = 'true')
  ) = 2
```

you select only those form_names then, that have the field_name rows has-wp-user and paid-membership-fee with values null and true respectively. Now you can join on the original table again, which filters out only allowed form_names and conveniently select the rows you need.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the fastest solution, so if performance is an issue we can address that. Otherwise, this is what I'd do...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(submit_time DECIMAL(13,2)
,form_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
,field_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
,field_value VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
,field_order INT NOT NULL
,file INT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(submit_time,form_name,field_name)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1387497601.83,'Bli medlem','has-wp-user','',0,NULL),
(1387497601.83,'Bli medlem','paid-membership-fee','true',1,NULL),
(1387497601.83,'Bli medlem','your-name','Williamsson',2,NULL),
(1387497601.83,'Bli medlem','your-email','Williamsson@mail.com',3,NULL),
(1387497601.83,'Bli medlem','your-adress','',4,NULL),
(1387497601.83,'Bli medlem','your-zip','',5,NULL),
(1387497601.83,'Bli medlem','your-postal-area','',6,NULL),
(1387497601.83,'Bli medlem','your-phonenumber','',7,NULL);

CREATE VIEW v_my_table AS
SELECT submit_time
     , form_name
     , MAX(CASE WHEN field_name = 'has-wp-user' THEN field_value END) has_wp_user
     , MAX(CASE WHEN field_name = 'paid-membership-fee' THEN field_value END) paid_membership_fee
     , MAX(CASE WHEN field_name = 'your-name' THEN field_value END) your_name
     , MAX(CASE WHEN field_name = 'your-email' THEN field_value END) your_email
     , MAX(CASE WHEN field_name = 'your-adress' THEN field_value END) your_address
     , MAX(CASE WHEN field_name = 'your-zip' THEN field_value END) your_zip
     , MAX(CASE WHEN field_name = 'your-postal-area' THEN field_value END) your_postal_area
     , MAX(CASE WHEN field_name = 'your-phonenumber' THEN field_value END) your_phonenumber
  FROM my_table
 GROUP
    BY submit_time
     , form_name;

SELECT your_name
     , your_email 
  FROM v_my_table 
 WHERE has_wp_user = '' 
   AND paid_membership_fee = 'true';
+------------+----------------------+
| your_name  | your_email           |
+------------+----------------------+
| Williamsson| Williamsson@mail.com |
+------------+----------------------+
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'd need, thanks!
Although, how does this work with more than one person in the my_table? Cause the view I got now gave me only one entry, and the other fields (address, zip, postal, phonenumber) isn't related to the email or name.

Or is this because some paid_membership_fee fields are empty?

This is definetly along what I need anyhow, thanks once again!

Comment: The view will create a separate row for each form_name. If you want something else then you'll have to explain more about how your data works.

Comment: I updated the first post with a DDL after removing the actual user data

Comment: @Williamsson I have to ask again since I didn't get an answer: "Is there a column that groups those rows together, like a user_id or something?" Cause your data doesn't make any sense. How do you know to which user an email address for example belongs? Tell me the column name and/or have a look at my answer. It's really simple once we know the column.

Comment: @fancyPants It can only be (submit_time,form_name)

Comment: @fancyPants Sorry, I missed your comment. Yes, for some reason the plugin uses submit_time, form_name and field_name as keys (BTREE, no unique) instead of only one id. I'm painfully aware that the data dosen't make any sense, this plugin is a pain in the bum to work with, haha :)

Comment: @Williamsson Updated my answer accordingly.